Convert class type to object type
Question
Given the type typeof MyClass, how can I convert that type into just MyClass?
Problem
In TypeScript, you can pass a class directly into a function, and then construct an instance of that class inside the function.
class MyClass {}

const init = (constructor: typeof MyClass): MyClass => {
  return new constructor()
}

// `myInstance` is of type `MyClass`
const myInstance = init(MyClass)

But what if you have children classes that inheret from a parent?
class Parent {}
class ChildA extends Parent {}
class ChildB extends Parent {}

const init2 = <T extends typeof Parent>(constructor: T) => {
  return new constructor()
}

// `childA` and `childB` are of type `Parent`
// I want `childA` to be of type `ChildA`
// I want `childB` to be of type `ChildB`
const childA = init2(ChildA)
const childB = init2(ChildB)

How can I set the return type of init2 to be the specific class I'm instantiating?
Playground

• Empty classes make for poor examples because they are interchangeable. Please add differing structure to them so Parent and ChildB are actually different types. • Once you do that you could use InstanceType<T> or even better, make T the instance type to begin with as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or, more likely, find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

Oh awesome, InstanceType is what I was looking for. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it.
